# Under extrusion caused by sharp turns(?)

Tags: ultimaker-cura, artillery-sidewinder-x1

I have been testing my brain for the last few weeks trying to solve this problem:
[image: Under extrusion]
Some info:

- Printers: Sidewinder X1 | Prusa MK3S
- Extruder: Stock(Titan clone with volcano clone hotend) | Stock
- Nozzle: 0.4 mm
- Filaments: eSun PLA+ | 3DFillies PLA+
- Slicer: Cura 4.6
- Firmware:Marlin 2.0.5.3 (Manual Mesh Bed Leveling,S Curve
  Acceleration,Linear Advance,Junction Deviation)
- Firmware Settings:

```
Recv: echo: M92 X80.12 Y80.12 Z399.78 E425.50
Recv: echo:; Maximum feedrates (units/s):
Recv: echo:  M203 X500.00 Y500.00 Z12.00 E120.00
Recv: echo:; Maximum Acceleration (units/s2):
Recv: echo:  M201 X1000.00 Y1000.00 Z500.00 E10000.00
Recv: echo:; Acceleration (units/s2): P<print_accel> R<retract_accel> T<travel_accel>
Recv: echo:  M204 P500.00 R500.00 T500.00
Recv: echo:; Advanced: B<min_segment_time_us> S<min_feedrate> T<min_travel_feedrate> J<junc_dev>
Recv: echo:  M205 B20000.00 S0.00 T0.00 J0.06
Recv: echo:; Home offset:
Recv: echo:  M206 X0.00 Y0.00 Z0.00
Recv: echo:; PID settings:
Recv: echo:  M301 P14.11 I1.16 D42.77
Recv: echo:  M304 P244.21 I45.87 D325.08
Recv: echo:; Linear Advance:
Recv: echo:  M900 K0.15
```

- Printed from USB Stick.
- E-Steps calibrated
- Flow calibrated
- Bed warped(low in the center) but with manual mesh bed leveling calibrated until my BLTouch arrives.

At first I assumed it was related to linear advance, however, decreasing it did help it reintroduced bulging corners. Then I noticed the geared extruder clicking(only sounded like vibrations caused by fast print speeds) during the Linear Advance retractions/deretractions. I then tried significantly lowering the max extruder feedrate/acceleration/jerk (jerk wasn't actually listed in the `M503` but I still tried sending the G-code to change it) in firmware, which did stop the clicking (skipped steps?) but not the under extrusion. Also im curious what the "Jerk Contol" settings in Cura actually do since I'm using junction deviation and if I should be using the lower values(0.02-0.1) that junction deviation calls for over the higher(5-30) ones that classic jerk does.

Things I have tried:

- Filament path clear
- Filament idler tension increased/decreased
- Temp: 180-205 °C
- Speed: 45 mm/s(25 mm/s Outer Walls)-125mm/s(75mm/s Outer Walls)
- Flow: Increasing slightly helped but lost dimensional accuracy which I need a high as I can get
- Retraction:0.05 mm-1.5 mm
- Retraction Speed: 20 mm/s-80 mm/s
- Combing, Wiping and Coasting: on/off
- Changing filament colour
- Changing filament brand
- Cold pulls
- Lowering Linear Advance(helped but reintroduced bulging corners)
- Junction Deviation: 0.02 - 0.08
- Seam: Expose seam(seemed to have the largest effect overall (but only
  on the calibration cubes,the reciever seen above also has the expose
  seem option enabled see:https://imgur.com/gallery/dRjptkp)
- Using PrusaSlicer(Couldnt establish any worthwile comparisons as
  something unrelated was causing major issues and my MK3 is currently out of order,
  see:https://imgur.com/gallery/WxJs2Qk)

Im fairly certain it is a Cura specific setting causing this and not any physical failure,however I have tried so many troubleshooting solutions with little to no progress so at this time I am welcoming any suggestions(even if already listed above).

Cura settings with more examples:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIShE.jpg

My apologies if this seems like a raw data dump, I have mental troubles with explaining things.

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable to the X1 looks like it is direct drive but have you tried checking the Bowden tube couplers?

Comment: This might be a Marlin bug. There were several like this with JD, LA, and S curve and last I checked S curve with LA was not supported unless you do an experimental override.

Comment: It could also just be lost material inside the model from combing. Try turning combing off in the slicer or setting a very low distance limit (~1 mm) on it and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Since lowering LA helped I'm guessing it's the LA+JD bug in Marlin.

Comment: I think you were right about oozing material. With combing off ,1.5mm retraction and 0.6mm Z-hop preliminary tests look to have solved this issue, however it did noticabley lower surface quality which is also not ideal. Im going to experiment with longer than 2mm retraction lengths even though it is commonly advised against for direct drive setups. Im guessing the retraction just isnt long enough for this Volcano/Titan clone.